# ImportError: cannot import name 'read_pdf' from partially initialized module 'tabula' (most likely due to a circular import)

Tags: tabula-py

I uninstalled the previous tabula library (if any) using pip uninstall tabula to avoid conflicts. Then, I specifically installed the Python wrapper tabula-py with pip install tabula-py. Unfortunately, I'm still encountering an error during table extraction.

Java, a dependency for tabula-py, is installed on my C drive. I've double-checked the Java path configuration in my environment variables to ensure accessibility. Despite this, I suspect tabula-py might not be properly locating the Java installation.

My primary goal is to extract table data from a CAD drawing stored in PDF format.  Since tabula-py is designed for text-based tables, I'm open to alternative methods or libraries that can handle the specific structure of CAD drawing PDFs.